# Realistic-ness of Elementary Vector Addition Problems

Tags: vectors

When first introduced to vectors, specifically vector addition, I was given problems which specified something along the lines of:

> "Let  $v = <a,b> $ where $v$ is an abribtrary windspeed, and let $u = <c,d>$ where $u$ is the desired trajectory of an airplane. 
>   *What direction should the airplane fly to follow $u$?*
>   "

I understand how you would solve this (find a $k$ such that $k = (u + v)$), but I am wondering - *are planes/boats/vehicles ect directly translated by air currents?
 Is there not a scaling factor/coefficient of translation that would be applied?*

Comment: This is more of a question for [Aviation.SE], but in short: Yes, the motion of an airplane in flight is controlled and measured relative to the surrounding air, so you simply _add_ the velosity of the air relative to the ground and the velocity of the plane relative to the air. (It is the latter that determines which way the airplane needs to point and how hard its engines need to work).

Comment: Boats and land vehicles are a different matter, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical approximation for a complex physical problem. In reality, the force with which a body is dragged by a flow into which it is immersed depends on its shape and friction of the fluid with the materials of which its parts are constituted. So the real motion is very complex to determine.